# How can I charge EV battery with large plate and detect shorts

Tags: battery-charging, current-limiting

This is a general question but specific example. I want to charge a hoverboard-based robot using a 'docking' station. But I don't know how those know to only send current if the robot and nothing but the robot is touching.  There are a multitude of examples, like Roomba, Anki vector, Lenovo 'power by contact' laptop charger, etc.  For example here is the laptop charger:

[image]

Note that the dongle there has 2 metal contacts to touch any two of the contact plate's squares.

The point is that the current reliably doesn't shock you if you touch it and doesn't short if you place something metal. It just 'does nothing'.

The problem is that plate and dongle only handles 20V 3A and I need 42V 2A to charge the hoverboard. I would rather not add an extra transformer to the robot and anyways it would lower the amps to less than 2, so I'm wondering:

How can you make a 'charging contact' and make it avoid shorts and shocks? If I knew this, I could take the hardware and just replace some electronics and charge at the correct voltage/amps for the battery.

In other words, all I really need is to plug in the robot by contact. Just like Roomba and others, but I'm not sure the circuitry involved in that.

For reference here is the battery I'm charging:

[image]

NOTE:using arduino etc is preferred for simplifying circuitry

EDIT: image showing only available specs (if you know how to get datasheet let me know)

[image]

EDIT: Here is what i want to do. the power charger (black) is 2A 42V.  The battery is 36V 8000aH and can dischage 70Amps!

[image]

Comment: Where are your datasheets? What's the part no and datasheet for the battery? Have you measured the volts across the metal contacts on the chraging plate? If you connect a suitably sized resitor across the charging plate's metal contacts, what do you get? It is simple at those kind of voltages to avoid shocks: you have a low voltage so don't need to do anything else, a bit of basic intelegent control of it would improve matters (put a voltage across the pads for 10ms, measure current draw, if it's within suitable range, turn on constant current supply for charging, otherwise off, repeat at 1Hz)

Comment: @Puffafishq thank you for the list of experiments.  as I understand I should
1. put a voltmeter between two plates (i expect to get zero volts or 20 volts).
2. place a 100Ohm resistor between two squares (i expect to get 0 or .2A)

as for  "turn on constant current supply for charging, otherwise off, repeat at 1Hz" i don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Puffafish regarding "you have low voltage so don't need to do anything else" i would like to pass 42 volts 2 amps through the plate. is that not a concern for shocks?

Comment: How do you get two reading for the voltage across the contacts? I'm assuming you mean you get 20V between them? You aren't passing 42V through anything, you are putting 42V across the contacts. 42VDC is offically "low votlage" and so needs very little protection. You can design a simple charger with two metal contacts. I'm not sure what you want for an answer from this question.

Comment: @Puffafish ok, so to clarify, If have a 42V 2A power supply  with positive and negative wires touching two big copper plates, and then from my battery, i have two big copper plates, and i touch the plates together, to complete the charging circuit, if I lay metal object across the two copper plates, it won't risk a big spark, and touching it won't hurt?  It will at least make an instant short circuit though. and in fact the battery has 40Amps and at that point would be making a short circuit

Comment: @Puffafish I added a render of what i am wanting to do. Given the circumstances, you don't think it needs any circuitry at all?

Comment: @Puffafish ie you wouldn't worry about a baby touching that?

Comment: I suppose I am thinking that board from lenovo has some chip that is so fast that it can turn off in a nanosecond before you can get shocked or cause short circuit or something.

Answer (score 0):

directly touching positive/negative terminals of the 42V 70Amp battery will generally not hurt at all. Just a little tingle.  So there is no 'shock' danger.

The danger you need to worry about is 'short circuits'. on the power supply side, your supply may already handle short circuits and shut off. If your battery has a BMS (it does) it will also likely blow a fuse or just turn off, but not without potentially doing a big arc and burning something.

so in other words, if you place a metal bar that short circuits the charger plates, probably your power supply will just 'protect itself'. (or if not you should get a differnt power supply.

However, if you place a bar across the plates when the battery is connected, sparks will fly and damage will occur. no amount of circuitry will stop the current from flowing between your barthat you laid across the contacts.  but technically the charging pad is not involved there as the bar is directly shorting your battery.

But if you consider the lenovo device, it has circuitry on both sides. so if you stick a bar across the plates while it is connected, the protection circuit is triggered so there is no longer a short on your battery.

so you can make your own 'dongle' by making a board like in your image and adding a circuit protector like this:

[image]

So, your charger will disconnect the circuit in case of short, and your dongle will disconnect in case of short.  And you won't get shocked.

I'm not sure if you will still get sparks from the short circuit.

Comment: Before downvoting, this is really just an 'example' of what kind of answer i need